# Textblock doesn't display on Windows Phone 10

Tags: textblock, windows-10-universal

So I create a new blank universal project, drag in a Textblock, enter "Hello World" as the content and start debug session. But the text doesn't display on the screen. I've tried with both virtual device (simulator) and real phone.

But running as a windows app (on local machine) does shows the text. Also other controls work too, like textbox or an image (on both PC and phone).

Does anyone know what I did wrong? I've just started learning Universal app. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have the same foreground that has page background?

Comment: No, I've tried changing text color or foreground of the textblock. Also please notice that when running as a desktop app it does display, just doesn't work when run as mobile app.

Comment: I haven't problem on my Lumia 930. Maybe, you can upload your sample, and I check it on my phone?

Comment: Thank you for your will, I really appreciate,

Comment: I've found that this is an issue related to positioning. I've changed some layout attributes, the design screen setting is for 5" devices, while debugging with virtual and real device are at a smaller size, so that those textblocks have jumped out to somewhere else. I'll study more about this. Thanks for your help.